# How does the implementation of vector work without getting problems with object initialization?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

If I were to implement a vector class, I'd use a dynamically allocated array internally to store the items. Whenever that buffer would become to small, I would create a new buffer double the size, copy over the items, and delete the old buffer - thus not needing to regrow the buffer each time an item is pushed.

This approach has some serious problem in C++: It's impossible to allocate an array (new[]) of a type with no default constructor. Obviously std::vector somehow works around that limitation as it allows me to use any item type I want - even if it has no default constructor.

I tried to look at the source code, but it seems to be just turtles all the way down - using endless amounts of code and some serious black magic.
I would really appreciate someone explaining how this works under the hood - if possible in a more comprehensible way than the source does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying mechanism to decouple memory allocation from object lifetime is:

- call an allocation function to allocate raw memory without creating objects
- use placement-new to create objects in that memory
- call their destructors directly to destroy the objects without releasing memory
- call a deallocation function to deallocate the memory.

which, in code, looks something like

```
void * memory = operator new(capacity() * sizeof(T));  // allocate memory
T * object = new(memory) T;                            // create an object
T->~T();                                               // destroy it
operator delete(memory);                               // deallocate memory
```

where `operator new` and `operator delete` are the default allocation and deallocation functions, used by `new` and `delete` expressions.

For standard containers, this is wrapped up in an "allocator" class, with a member function to do each of these operations; you can provide your own allocator if you have special needs that aren't met by the default [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Comment: So, basically you could say that placement new and manual destructor invocation were added to the language to enable black magic with raw memory segments?

Comment: "use placement-new to create objects in that memory" - the allocator interface actually provides the functions for [creating objects at specific addresses](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct), and [destroying them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy), so the vector-level code probably shouldn't be doing that itself....

Comment: @TonyD: Indeed, as I said in the last paragraph, the underlying mechanism is abstracted into a class, and the container uses that.

Comment: @BillAskaga: That's a common use for them, yes. They can also be useful for unions of non-trivial types (since C++11).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: oh yup - reads better with your edit too.  Will leave my comment above for the links.  Cheers and +1.

Comment: @BillAskaga: yet another (obscure) use for placement-`new` is to overwrite an object with another without having the first's destructor invoked - that's only valid if the rest of the program doesn't depend on the side effects of the not-invoked destructor - which is vague enough that the technique's best avoided unless there's a clear need and experienced programmer.